# Apache ssl Naked Domain not finding VirtualHost

Tags: apache, ssl

We have a UC Certificate with 4 SANs. One of those SANs is the naked domain name, i.e. domain.com.

We have ssl working fine and pointing to the correct Virtual Host directories for each of the SANs except for the main or naked domain name. For some reason that I can't figure out, Apache is serving up the default DocumentRoot from the main httpd.conf file when the naked domain is requested.

We're running Apache 2.4 in Linux.
The httpd.conf file includes *.conf files in the conf.d/ directory.

We created a file called virtual.conf, and the contents are:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot    /data/www/html/domain/public
    ServerName      domain.com
    ServerAlias     *.domain.com
    SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/data/www/html/zf2/library"

    <Directory      /data/www/html/domain/public >
            DirectoryIndex  index.php
            AllowOverride   All
            Order           allow,deny
            Allow           from all
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot    /data/www/html/domain/public
    ServerName      domain.com
    SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/data/www/html/zf2/library"

    SSLEngine               on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/pki/tls/private/leaders.key

    <Directory      /data/www/html/domain/public >
            DirectoryIndex  index.php
            AllowOverride   All
            Order           allow,deny
            Allow           from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot    /data/www/html/domain/public
    ServerName      va.domain.com
    SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/data/www/html/zf2/library"

    SSLEngine               on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/pki/tls/private/leaders.key
    <Directory      /data/www/html/domain/public >
            DirectoryIndex  index.php
            AllowOverride   All
            Order           allow,deny
            Allow           from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Presently we have each of the virtual hosts pointing to the same folder on the server.

Can anyone see why calling https://domain.com causes Apache to serve the default DocumentRoot location (located in httpd.conf) rather than the Directory specified in this VirtualHost directive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the VirtualHost directive required the use of an internal network IP address attribute. So

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
```

must be

```
 <VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:443>
```

or whatever the internal network IP address is.

I had tried using the public IP Address, which caused Apache to fail when launched. So, the public IP won't work, but the network IP will.

Answer (score 1):

According to an [article](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) at Apache's wiki you cannot configure Named Virtual Hosts for SSL. The problem is that to figure out which Virtual Host must be referred you must have the contents of the "Host" header from HTTP request. However, in case of SSL your request is encrypted, thus you do not have that information. That is why the Virtual Host matching is performed relying on the IP (or interface) address (IP-based Virtual Host).

Although, the good thing is that you may have multiple Virtual Hosts (with the IP address of course) in case if your subdomains are of the same domain (like it is in the example of the article, one.example.com, two.example.com, etc.).